# Build Android Chat App using GCM without Implementing Server Side App

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I want to implement android chat application using Google Cloud Messaging (GCM), but the difference here that I do not want to implement server side code using PHP (or other web language) and MySQL database.

The Scenario which I want is, My Application communicates with the GCM server for both sending and receiving incoming messages without needing for implement PHP pages in my server to communicate with the GCM server. In other words, Chat Application sends the message to GCM server then the GCM server forward that message to target device using.

Is above Scenario possible, how?
Thanks for all...

Comment: So, in your app you want the have the ability for users to broadcast GCM messages to all other users of the apps?

Comment: All I need for it is sending messages from user to other without needing for PHP code like this http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best would have been if you implemented your own XMPP server for GCM.
But if you really do not want to build a server you need to look into Mobile Backend as a service (MBaaS).

[this](http://www.anypresence.com/solutions/mbaas/) or [this](http://quickblox.com/)(Recommended) are the things you need. But note that they all are free till a specified limit, you'll have to pay if you have a large user base.

Also, you can search for other MBaaS services on google.